# Design application with high database interaction and intermediate computations in .NET

Tags: .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, architecture

Working on a service which hits database multiple times and does lots of computation that data in .net code and then saves it back to database tables.

there are certain columns which need to be computed from other DB columns from other tables(that information is also stored in database but we would cache that data).That information gives a sqlquery having all dependent column values for each calculated column.

The problem is I dont want to hit the database for each calculated column (it can go upto 300-400 calls in single operation.

What i can think of is get all the relevant data initially in sort of Model and the query from those model objects instead of sql tables.(Can Entity framework be used for this?)

But since there is dependency on sqlqueries as well that i mentioned above, i need to convert sql queries so that they can run on objects(converting sql query to linq)

Is there any API to convert sqlquery to linq? or any better standard design approach for this whole problem.

Edit 1: The use case here is that I have already populated the entities by running sql queries.Once the entities are populated , after this step, I want to run some other sql queries on the data that I have fetched in entities and that SQL query I want to run is joining more than one table(entities in my case). For that only option I can see is write my own custom SQL to LINQ parser.I hope it clears the question

Comment: So are you asking if you can cache data in memory using Entity Framework?  And why is it you don't want to use a SQL query to retrieve the data?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I am doing computing in code on few entities(tables) for 300 columns ,so i dont want to hit those few tables again and again on database 300times. So I think its better to fetch those entities data initially and then execute queries on entities itself.

Comment: Sure.  EF Entities are just ordinary .NET types.  Once you fetch them from the database you can keep them around.  Even without EF you can store the data in memory with a DataTable or in custom types.

Comment: yes @DavidBrowne-Microsoft totally agreed on that front and that is the way I am looking forward(Most probably custom types approach) but for my second part of question the queries that would be fetching the data are sqlqueries ,so i need to convert them to linq (I suppose!) so that i can run them on entity objects? Do we have any API for this or I need to write a complete sql to linq parser from scratch.

Comment: You can use regular SQL queries to load in EF, or just open a DataReader with the results and populate your entities in code.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbSet_SqlQuery_System_String_System_Object___

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The use case here is that I have already populated the entities by running sql queries(as you suggested above) once the entities are populated , after this step, I want to run some other sql queries on the data that I have fetched in entities and that sql query i want to run is joining more than one table(entities in my case). For that only option I can see is write my own custom SQL to LINQ parser.I hope it clears the question.

Comment: What's the nature of the computations? If this is *from* data in the database, is going to *put* some new data in the database and is *about* just data in the database, it's better to try and push those computations down *into* the database too.

Comment: Why not just manually convert the queries to LINQ to Objects, or plain C# code?